# Breaking up "年収だってこんなにあんのよ"

Tags: grammar, translation, colloquial-language

I'm having a hard time understanding "年収だってこんなにあんのよ" so please help me fill in the holes!

年収: annual income
だって: as for (?)
こんなに: like this
あんの: ??

Answer (score 1):

年収だってこんなにあんのよ is a colloquial form of 年収だってこんなにあるのよ. This is equivalent to 年収もこんなにあるのよ and it means "The salary is this high, too".

The use of も in 年収も indicates there were other good aspects, and the speaker is adding another good aspect to what was already discussed (年収). こんなにある means some quantity is visible to the listener, too, and the speaker is indicating they assess that quantity to be quite high. So in the case, the listener must be aware of how much the 年収 is.

By adding のよ, the speaker indicates this fact explains something or should be a reason to reconsider something. E.g. 「年収もこんなにあるのよ。そらフェラーリくらい買うでしょ」、「年収もこんなにあるのよ。よりを戻しなさいよ」